# Volume of revolution with rotating shaded area

Tags: tikz-pgf

I did the following MFWs for teaching the notion of Volume of Revolution in Calculus. I started with:

```
‎\documentclass[a4paper,openany,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
‎\usepackage{pgfplots,relsize}‎
‎\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}‎‎
‎\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}‎
‎‎\begin{document}‎‎‎
‎‎\begin{tikzpicture}‎
‎\begin{axis}[axis lines = middle‎, ‎smooth‎, ‎xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$‎, ‎xmax=4‎, ‎xmin=-4‎, ‎ymax=3‎, ‎ymin=-3]‎‎
\addplot [name path=A‎,   line width=1pt‎‎‎,  ‎black, domain=0:pi‎‎] ({3*cos(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x))});‎‎
\addplot [name path=B‎,   thin‎‎‎,  ‎black, domain=-3:3‎‎] {0};‎‎
\addplot [  thin‎‎‎,  ‎black, domain=0:2‎‎] ({0},{x});‎
‎‎\addplot [gray!20] fill between [of=A and B];‎
‎\end{axis}‎
‎\pgftext[base,x=1cm,y=5.1cm,rotate=0] {\small{$f(x)=2\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{9}$}}};‎
\end{tikzpicture}‎
\end{documents}
```

to indicate that the flat surface under the function is going to rotate about `x` axis and then the following will be expose:

```
‎\documentclass[a4paper,openany,12pt]{article}‎
‎\usepackage{pgf,tikz}‎
\usepackage{pgfplots,relsize}
‎\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}‎‎
‎\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}‎
‎‎\begin{document}‎‎‎
‎\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}‎
\begin{axis}[ view={15}{30},grid=major]
\addplot3[fill opacity=0.25,
        surf, 
        samples=25,shader=interp,
        domain=0:6,y domain=0:6,
        z buffer=sort]
    ({5*cos(deg(x))*sin(deg(y))},{3*sin(deg(x))*sin(deg(y))},{2*cos(deg(y)) });‎
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}‎
 \end{center} ‎
 \end{document}‎
```

to illustrate formed volume of rotating. Can I made **the curve of the function and its shaded area below** it in the 3d plot simultaneously? Please see the fig below. I did for another function by Maple (it is just a sample):

[image]

I did the code for parametric form `({3*cos(x)},{0},{2*sin(x)})`, but it failed as I had expected. It seems that the curve was not fitted on the ellipsoid properly.  Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ view={-15}{30},grid=major]
\addplot3[%fill opacity=0.25,
        surf,samples=25,shader=interp,
        domain=0:pi/3,y domain=0:2*pi,
        z buffer=sort]
    ({x},{cos(deg(x))*sin(deg(y))},{cos(deg(x))*cos(deg(y))});
\addplot3[samples=25,blue,thick,
        domain=0:pi/3,samples y=0,
        z buffer=sort]
    ({x},{cos(deg(x))*sin(deg(50))},{cos(deg(x))*cos(deg(50))});    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the time. I really wanted to show the function which makes the volume as a visible curve. See the plot above. I want that blue curve be visible. However , the visibility of the shaded area as it could be seen in the above plot is my aim here for the ellipsioid.

Comment: I used the opacity above as a code to make the shaded rotating are visible.

Comment: @mrs Could you please edit your question to make it clearer. I fail to see that you plot an ellipsoid. And when you edit it, use a tool like [this one](https://pteo.paranoiaworks.mobi/diacriticsremover/) to remove all non-ascii characters that may prevent others from testing your code.

Comment: Thanks again for what you have done. Regards.